# Android layout align on visibility possibly gone

Tags: android, android-layout

This is a general question about layout : I have 2 elements, a SeekBar and an AdView

```
    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_above="@+id/admob"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="10"/>
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.bleezworld.lovescore"
        android:id="@+id/admob"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="xxxx"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
```

I just moved to the new Google Play Ads (much harder to enable than the old framework). In the old `Adview`, the view had automatically a height of 0 pixels if the ad was not loaded, else 50px. The Seekbar would then be at the bottom of the screen, of just above the ad, very smoothly.

Now the ad leaves a blank space. I am thinking of setting the visibility to `GONE` in the adview listener (onfailed, ...).

So 2 questions :

- how did you cope with the migration in this case (reimplementing `onFailed`, ...)
- Is there a clean way to remove a layout that is aligned to the bottom such that layouts that are just above it become aligned to the bottom too ?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that they've added some sort of margining to the adview when it fails to load?

To remove an element (beyond just setting its visibility to GONE), you can try this:

```
((ViewManager) mAdView.getParent()).removeView(mAdView);
```

Your seekbar might get mad at you if you do that though, as you'd be removing a view that it's trying to align itself with.